# How can I access Elasticsearch's cluster stats using the transport client?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch 1.4. How can I access the [Cluster Stats API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-stats.html#cluster-stats) from Java, using the Transport Client?